# replacing text in a file, Python

Tags: python, file, str-replace

so this piece of code is meant to take a line from a file and replace the certain line from the string with a new word/number, but it doesn't seem to work :(

```
else:
    with open('newfile', 'r+')as myfile:
           x=input("what would you like to change: \nname \ncolour \nnumber \nenter   option:")
           if x == "name":
               print("your current name is:")
               test_lines = myfile.readlines()
               print(test_lines[0])
               y=input("change name to:")
               content = (y)
               myfile.write(str.replace((test_lines[0]), str(content)))
```

I get the error message TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given), i don't know why (content) is not accepted as an argument. This also happens for the code below

```
if x == "number":
          print ("your current fav. number is:")
          test_lines = myfile.readlines()
          print(test_lines[2])
          number=(int(input("times fav number by a number to get your new number \ne.g 5*2 = 10 \nnew number:")))
          result = (int(test_lines[2])*(number)) 
          print (result)
          myfile.write(str.replace((test_lines[2]), str(result)))





f=open('newfile', 'r')
print("now we will print the file:")
for line in f:
    print (line)
f.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace is a function of a 'str' object.

Sounds like you want to do something like (this is a guess not knowing your inputs)

```
test_lines[0].replace(test_lines[0],str(content))
```

I'm not sure what you're attempting to accomplish with the logic in there. looks like you want to remove that line completely and replace it?

also i'm unsure what you are trying to do with

```
content = (y)
```

the output of input is a str (which is what you want)

**EDIT:**

In your specific case (replacing a whole line) i would suggest just reassigning that item in the list. e.g.

```
test_lines[0] = content
```

To overwrite the file you will have to truncate it to avoid any race conditions. So once you have made your changes in memory, you should seek to the beginning, and rewrite everything.

```
# Your logic for replacing the line or desired changes
myfile.seek(0)
for l in test_lines:
    myfile.write("%s\n" % l)
myfile.truncate()
```

Comment: Actually I think he wants to replace the first character in test_lines with content, so:`test_lines.replace(test_lines[0],str(content))`. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed. My bad.

Comment: Yeah,  I want to completely remove the line and replace it, the code you gave worked for the argument error but the old line is still there despite the fact that there's also the new line there. thanks for the answers dude, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test_lines = myfile.readlines()
print(test_lines[0])
y = input("change name to:")
content = str(y)
myfile.write(test_lines[0].replace(test_lines[0], content))
```

You have no object known purely as `str`. The method `replace()` must be called on a string object. You can call it on `test_lines[0]` which refers to a string object.

However, you may need to change your actual program flow. However, this should circumvent the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it as `test_lines[0].replace(test_lines[0],str(content))`

Calling `help(str.replace)` at the interpreter.

> replace(...)
>      S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> str
>
> Return a copy of S with all occurrences of substring
>      old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
>      given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

Couldn't find the docs.